# Remove Raid-0 and reinstall windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios, raid-0, usb-boot, clean-install

I have recently bought this laptop: [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N7TWAYC).

Unfortunately, it comes with two 256 GB SSD's in Raid 0. I do not want this, so I will break the raid configuration.

HOWEVER, because Windows is installed on this configuration, it will break as well. How do I reinstall windows with the least amount of hassle?
Here's my current plan:

1. Create a recovery drive through windows 10.
2. Boot into BIOS, and delete the raid 0 configuration.
3. Shut down the computer, and then remove one of the hard drives.
4. Boot up from USB.
5. Clean install windows.

Is this fool-proof? Is there anything else I should do?
Thank you.

Comment: Download ISO, create installation Media, Boot to media and install Windows.  Your license key will automatically be detected, once installed, Windows will already be activated.

Comment: Would this be better/fool-proof compared to making a recovery drive?

Comment: You cannot install Windows with a recovery disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of making a recovery drive, make sure to use installation media instead, as Ramhound said.

ALSO, if this is an NVMe drive, make sure to get the correct RST drivers from intel, otherwise windows will not recognize the drives.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Copy of your Windows OS on your new drive. Boot in to safe mode restart and boot into Bios. Change from RAID Config to AHCI save and exit. PC will boot into safe mode AHCI drivers should be loaded. Switch off remove one RAID SSD and install your New Drive with windows on it and Switch on.